# Get the pure HTML from an AJAX Page

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, web-services, html

We're making a HTML5 offline app. We need to serve up a series of HTML pages supplied by a 3rd party offline. They have AJAX calls in them that fetches and displays extra data once the page has been downloaded. This will not work in an HTML5 offline app where there is no internet connection.

Our main idea is to have the iPad connect to a JSON webservice when there is an internet connection. The webservice then requests the HTML pages, downloads them and lets the AJAX run. Then the DOM will contain all the markup it requires (including the data from AJAX). This HTML page is then returned to the HTML5 offline app.

Is there a very very simple way of doing this? I pre-written library would be perfect. Is there a better option?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas from the top of my head. Honesly not checked myself, so take it as brainstorming.

1. I would check of body.innerHtml contains the modified DOM, or still the loaded Html.
   If modified, you may be able to retrieve it by simply writing it to a textarea via Javascript and copy/paste it.
2. Maybe its possible to modify the ajax call to save the data to Localstorage at the first call, and get it from there on other executions without ajax call.

As I said, just some ideas in case noone else provides a concrete solution.

Hope it helps
cheers
sascha